# How to keep track of my location when the application is not launched?

Tags: android, service, gps

I am developing an application where I am required to get the latitude and longitude of a user and save it into a database. I am required to notify the user when he reaches the same place. i have used Services for this. But I just wanted to know whether the service will keep on running when the application is not launched or will it keep running throughout monitoring my location?

Comment: it keep running throughout monitoring your location

Comment: I want it to keep running even when the application is not launched.

Comment: if once your app is launched,your service is running in background .but you want to keep running this service when app not launch .then its not possible

Comment: That is what I am asking.. How to make it run when the app is not launched?

Comment: I told that its not possible as per android lifecycle.